# 2 UL menus at either end of a nav container

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 2 ul menus in a nav container one menu is floating left and the other right. I've tried to get the menus to sit at the bottom of the nav container using `vertical-align: bottom` but they still sit at the top. Is there a way to get them to drop down to the bottom?

CSS / HTML

```css
nav {
  background-color: red;
  height: 40px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#men1 li {
  float: left;
}
#men1:after {
  clear: both;
}
#men2 li {
  float: right;
}
#container {
  clear: both;
}
a {
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul id="men1">
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="men2">
    <li><a href="#home">Home2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#news">News2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div id="container">
</div>
```

Comment: try to use position:absolute; bottom:0;

Comment: what do you mean with sit on the bottom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to play with `position` attribute. Here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ajzy3ubs/) and a working example here:

```css
nav {
  background-color: red;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
}
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 50%;
}
nav > ul#men1 > li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 0.7em;
}
nav > ul#men2 > li {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 0.7em;
}
ul#men1 {
  left: 0px;
}
ul#men2 {
  right: 0px;
}
a {
  display: block;
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul id="men1">
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="men2">
    <li><a href="#home">Home2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#news">News2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Please add code snippets directly to your answers in the future; links can go dead. I've added it for you this time :)

Comment: Thanks @misterManSam, I didn't even know you could put running code snipets directly on SO, awesome!

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly:
Here is a [**working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LdqmtLw8/1/)

Important parts:
set `nav` position to relative

```
nav{
    position: relative;
    ...
}
```

*(the reason for [position relative](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/) is that position absolute elements must be in a position relative div)*

Then add two more css for `men1` and `men2` like so:

```
#men1 {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0; //similar to float: left; but because of the position:abolute; part, float wont work
}
#men2 {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a big fan of [`display: table`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#Values) for things like this. [Compatible IE8 +](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table)

- The two unordered lists are given `display: table` and `height: 100%` to fill the nav height
- The two unordered list "tables" are floated left and right as they are in your example
- The list items are given `display: table-cell`
- `vertical-align: bottom` will now work as expected

### Working Example

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav {
  background-color: red;
  height: 40px;
}
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
}
#men1 {
  float: left;
}
#men2 {
  float: right;
}
nav li {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  width: 60px;
}
a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul id="men1">
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="men2">
    <li><a href="#home">Home2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#news">News2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```